# Notification Architecture

Tags: silverlight, iis, hosting, windows-phone-7, push

With the arrival of WP7, I developed a solution to business appointments. And I wonder about the architecture. My Silverlight application needs to communicate with web services, no problem here.

By cons, I have another need that is a push to notify phones with the Microsoft Notification Push Service. My problem is how to handle this server side.

1. First problem, IIS has a timeout and I need to push to ensure WP7 if an appointment.
2. Second problem, there will be a lot
   of appointments.

I thought of an IIS / WAS to host the WCF services and a Windows service that handles notifications Push, for each new appointment creates a timer to send the push.

Have you an idea of architecture for this solution? Do you know a server / library planning?

Best regards,

Vincent BOUZON

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entriely sure what your question is but it may be useful to clarify the following:

> Push notification messages will not
>   have guaranteed delivery.

If you need to guarantee adding appointments to a persons device, so they don't miss any business appointments, why not have the person subscribe to a shared calendar and remotely update the calendar from the server? Or send a meeting request via Exchange/email?

With regard to the volume of appointments, you can send up to 500 notifications per app, per device, per day. I don't think you'll reach that limit in terms of physical meeting appointments. Not unless you have some VERY busy people.

In terms of a process on a web server sending the messages, you could also consider having an Azure Worker Role generating the messages.

Comment: The problem is not adding appointments, but remind the appointment, if the application is not running (no multitasking on WP7), it's necessary to make a push to send a message to the user.

How to manage a set of scheduled push with my server and without Azure ?

Comment: Calendar appointments have built in reminder functionality. Why reimplement this yourself? Is there a problem with the built in behaviour you're trying to get around? If you must do this yourself, you'll need your service to monitor the appointments and send messages at the appropriate time. There's an article on MSDN about how to send a Push Notification at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545(VS.92).aspx

Comment: Simply because it is not simple appointments. And an application can not handle the internal calendar. And I know already how to send push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very timely [Channel9 video on push notifications](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone-04-Using-Push-Notification-Part-2/) that's probably worth watching.